# Why does compiling this code requires very high memory usage and time only in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

[Godbolt Link to the code](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/tJ8rZ7)

Logic: Computing a binomial coefficient over a few iterations using a Modular<> struct which is a wrapper over integer supporting modular arithmetic. Combinatorics struct contains two arrays of "Modular" integers, one for factorials and other for inverse factorials (modular multiplicative inverse of the corresponding factorial).

On Linux, compilation using GCC took over 3.3GB of memory and 100% CPU utilization for over 30 minutes, and thereafter I had to kill it. This hints for an infinite loop.

But other compilers like Clang, ICC, MSVC compiles this code successfully and well within limits.

Comment: I suggest posting a gcc bug/issue , this is not really a question for SO. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: If you change N=1000000 to N=200 for example you can see that gcc generates 200'ish assembly commands to initialize each individual array item. If N is large consider using vector instead as a workaround.

Comment: Also please post a MCVE and make the question self-contained.

Comment: @M.M, I tried posting a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95563), but nobody responded, so I thought it's something that I must be doing wrong.

Comment: @user202729, How can you do that? I don't know why is GCC causing this so I don't know why it is the case! If I knew, then I would have submitted a patch instead.

Comment: I meant to say to change N=200 in the code. Anyway vector should work, but you lose the constexpr-ness.

Comment: An MCVE can be as short as [this](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/yckdzF).